# During group by I need to take a variable which is not using in group by also I don't want to take its aggregation function (I want it as it is)

Tags: mysql, sql, pyspark

I have a data Frame that has millions of records and 8 columns.
I want to group by it with col1 and col2 and in select, I want *name_id*, max(SUM),col1,col2.

**Now the problem is I am not using name_id in a group by condition nor is it an aggregate function.**

Can you please suggest any method that solves my problem in SQL or Pyspark.

Input Data Frame here SUM = number of columns have data and name_id is unique:
[image: Screenshot 1]

Required Output : name_id (as it is), max(SUM),Col1,Col2 
[image: Screenshot 2]

I tried something like this but it's not working:
[image: Screenshot 3]

Any suggestion is welcome!

I tried below code which is working fine with one scenario and not with others.

[image: Tried Code]

Working scenario, When I have duplicate maximum values in sum column then its working fine and retuning max name_id which is my requirement
[image: Working Scenario]

When SUM columns do not have maximum value duplicate then it is returning null, in the below table according to logic my output should contain name_id = 48981 and name_id = 52214 but I am getting the only name_id = 52214. 
[image: Not Working Scenario]

Comment: I have several questions: 1. why `banana, green` is not in the result, and 2. how do you pick the `water melon,red` row in the expected result? In other words, why row `10005` and not row `10003`?

Comment: Yes, banana, green should be in the answer, I will update my question and i need a max of name_id if SUM column has the same values as in watermelon case.

Comment: It is better to add text than printscreens

Comment: Regarding the second example: I do not understand why do you require 365042 in the result and why 126585 is NOT in the required result.

Comment: Regarding the third example: the current output does not correspond to the query!

Comment: Regarding the second example: After the group by, we got two sets one gives output 1808346 and one 365042, it is working fine.

Comment: Regarding the third example: the current output I got only after running mentioned query.

Comment: which version of mysql are you using? 5.6?

Comment: I am running it in Pyspark - Databricks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a classical greatest per group problem. I would suggest using the following solution to this problem:

```
select d.*
from data_frame d
join (
    select col_1, col_2, 
       max(sum) max_sum, 
       max(name_id) max_name_id
    from data_frame
    group by col_1, col_2
) t on d.col_1 = t.col_1 and 
       d.col_2 = t.col_2 and
       d.name_id = t.max_name_id and
       d.sum = t.max_sum
```

Comment: Baca: I am checking data and found this logic is failing in a scenario where SUM column don't have duplicates value so query giving me null value .

Comment: @aamirmalik124 elaborate in your question using an example! Your comment doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want:

```
select max(name_id), max(sum), col1, col2, max(col3), . . .
from t
group by col1, col2;
```

Your last column doesn't seem to be using `max()`, but you have not explained that logic.

Comment: hi, Can you please recheck my requirement and give me some answer, Thanks!